# Retrieving metadata around documents in a library

Tags: 2013, document-library, web-services, rest, metadata

This may come across as a novice question, but I was hoping to gain some direction or advice in how to query SharePoint 2013 to retrieve the metadata (document properties, including the Document ID GUID) around each of the documents stored in a specific document library.  I do not have access to the Content SQL Server database, so I was hoping there would be some sort of web service I could leverage to get this information.  In the past, I have used the /_vti_bin/ListData.svc web service to retrieve information from a SharePoint list in XML format.  Is there a similar web service I could use to retrieve this information?

Some of the kind of data I am hoping to have returned is the library, uploader (created by), document type, and other custom columnar properties.

Comment: Are you interested in REST/JSON?

Comment: Yes, a REST web service that returns JSON would be more than great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For REST you can refer this msdn article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx

A typical REST call look as below

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')
```

You can use ODATA protocol for `filter`, `select`, `expand`, `order`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx

[image]

Comment: Thank you Amal! Exactly what I was looking for. Returned in XML format, now just have to handle some further parsing.  Thanks again.